# Spring boot webflux security with JWT token

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, spring-webflux

Trying to setup JWT token based auth with Spring boot webflux.

**Spring boot version :- 2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT**

**Tech Stacks:-** Angular 9, Spring boot 2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, Spring security, Spring security JWT

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

GUI is angular 9 based and using form based authentication.

Need JWT for call coming from angular and also call coming to the API directly.

**WebSecurityConfig,**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private ServerSecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository;

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securitygWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint((swe, e) -> {
            return Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {
                swe.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
            });
        }).accessDeniedHandler((swe, e) -> {
            return Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {
                swe.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
            });
        }).and().csrf().disable().formLogin().disable().httpBasic().disable()
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager).securityContextRepository(securityContextRepository)
                .authorizeExchange().pathMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll().pathMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .anyExchange().authenticated().and().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PBKDF2Encoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new PBKDF2Encoder();
    }

}
```

**PBKDF2Encoder,**

```
@Component
public class PBKDF2Encoder implements PasswordEncoder {
    @Value("${springbootwebfluxjjwt.password.encoder.secret}")
    private String secret;

    @Value("${springbootwebfluxjjwt.password.encoder.iteration}")
    private Integer iteration;

    @Value("${springbootwebfluxjjwt.password.encoder.keylength}")
    private Integer keylength;

    /**
     * More info (https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Hashing_Java)
     * 
     * @param cs password
     * @return encoded password
     */
    @Override
    public String encode(CharSequence cs) {
        try {
            byte[] result = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512")
                    .generateSecret(
                            new PBEKeySpec(cs.toString().toCharArray(), secret.getBytes(), iteration, keylength))
                    .getEncoded();
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(result);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(CharSequence cs, String string) {
        return encode(cs).equals(string);
    }
}
```

**AuthenticationManager,**

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationManager implements ReactiveAuthenticationManager {

    @Autowired
    private JWTUtil jwtUtil;

    @Override
    public Mono<Authentication> authenticate(Authentication authentication) {
        String authToken = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        String username;
        try {
            username = jwtUtil.getUsernameFromToken(authToken);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            username = null;
        }
        if (username != null && jwtUtil.validateToken(authToken)) {
            Claims claims = jwtUtil.getAllClaimsFromToken(authToken);
            List<String> rolesMap = claims.get("role", List.class);
            List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();
            for (String rolemap : rolesMap) {
                roles.add(Role.valueOf(rolemap));
            }
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                username,
                null,
                roles.stream().map(authority -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority.name())).collect(Collectors.toList())
            );
            return Mono.just(auth);
        } else {
            return Mono.empty();
        }
    }
}
```

**SecurityContextRepository,**

```
@Component
public class SecurityContextRepository implements ServerSecurityContextRepository {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> save(ServerWebExchange swe, SecurityContext sc) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<SecurityContext> load(ServerWebExchange swe) {
        ServerHttpRequest request = swe.getRequest();
        String authHeader = request.getHeaders().getFirst(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);

        if (authHeader != null && authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            String authToken = authHeader.substring(7);
            Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authToken, authToken);
            return this.authenticationManager.authenticate(auth).map((authentication) -> {
                return new SecurityContextImpl(authentication);
            });
        } else {
            return Mono.empty();
        }
    }

}
```

Is this the correct approach? Is there any better approach?

Comment: your code is written very "non-functional". Try/catch is never used in reactive programming, because it is blocking, and you don't throw exceptions either, you return Mono.errors() containing exceptions. The more things that are done in a context of a Mono/Flux the more the server can optimize by leveraging the ability of content switching threads., try instead returning a `Mono<String> `from your `jwtUtil.getUsernameFromToken` and `flatMap` over the result. And in the jwtUtil.getUsernameFromToken return either a Mono.empty or a Mono.error depending on how you want to handle it.

Comment: The approach depends in what you want to achieve. Your first problem is that you have to know what is happening there. I will suggest you to configure an AuthorizationWebFilter by your own and add an access authorization manager to check the incoming tokens, you could take a look at https://github.com/soasada/kotlin-coroutines-webflux-security where I explain more or less how to do it (in kotlin, but is the same for java)

Comment: @Nico, I dont see sample to get the custom claim on controller. I am setting 2 claims in token and need the same in the handler.

Answer (score 9):

I've faced same problems, and after lot of research I've made a fully 100% functional demo project implementing webflux + webflux-security + others...
you can find the complete implementation here: https://github.com/eriknyk/webflux-jwt-security-demo

the implementation contains:

- Spring webflux
- Spring security implemented with JWT + validation layer
- User register demo endpoint
- User authentication endpoint
- Model to dto mapping (using mapstruct)
- User R2db with Postgresql repository impl
- User validation in spring security layer, according to the user record in db

Comment: I'd like to thank you so much for creating that demo! I'd spent numerous hours trying to get it working correctly but with your example I got it working in an hour.